# No data from Nimbus weather application

Tags: appcenter

If I install the Nimbus application through the AppCenter it does not work, does not show any data. If I build from source and run it there are no issues. The AppCenter says it is version 1.10 and the source is also 1.10 so I am not sure what the issue is. A couple other people are having the same issue:  https://github.com/danirabbit/nimbus/issues/141s